# STM32F767ZI nucleo board not connecting with USB

Tags: stm32f7

I am new to using the STM32 nucleo board. I have bought an STM32F767ZI nucleo board. I installed the STM-link utility V4.6 version and stm-link009 drivers. When I connect the micro-USB port of nucleo to my computer, its not getting detected. The COM LED LD4 is blinking. From the manual, I saw that its trying to connect if the LD4 RED led is blinking.
I have tried different computer and different USB cables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the micro-USB cable. I had tried different USB cables which I thought was good and worked with my phone to transfer data. But didn't work with STM32F767ZI. I bought a new one and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

After I sent the previous post, I decided to try the 9th micro usb cable I could find in my house and as soon as the cable is plugged in, my PC recognizes the st-link debugger!
For people who is experiencing the same confusion, the working micro usb cable has "MUSUN" on the USB A side, but that may just be the brand of the cable. You may also try some new micro usb cable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).